# Enable file sharing only when on home Wi-Fi network in OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, bonjour

How can file/screen/other sharing on Mac OS X be enabled *only* when on a certain network, such as the home Wi-Fi network? Sharing should not be enabled when on public Wi-Fi network.

Currently it seems that it is only possible to globally enabled or disable sharing per service in System Preferences, Sharing.

Comment: The de facto program for this used to be [MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/), but I haven't used it for a while and based on their site, Snow Leopard support seems spotty, specifically for Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 3):

Even if slightly expensive, you can use [NetworkLocation](http://centrix.ca/NetworkLocation/) to autodetect your location, and after configuring it for your home network, add `Application` > `Open an Application / Run Script` and configure it so that it runs this [StartInternetSharing](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/79900/tools/StartInternetSharing.scpt) script. Repeat, only this time check the box saying `Launch when leaving location` and add the [StopInternetSharing](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/79900/tools/StopInternetSharing.scpt) script instead.

Scripts weren't written by me, but I've updated them and hosted them on my Dropbox because I have a checkbox for Xgrid, and so the original version wasn't working. I've tested them and they both work. Here is the [MacRumors post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=5463302&postcount=5) where these scripts were originally posted.

P.S. I don't know if I have Xgrid because of something I installed, or everyone with 10.6 does. Could you read/follow the instructions in either script's headers (open in AppleScript Editor) and let me know if you do? I'd like to update the scripts to have the most-used option as default. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine found an open source app called [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/feature-list/), which looks very promising and seems to be able to do exactly what we need. I just read that it is based on [MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/), which fideli had mentioned above.